# Find the basis for kernel of a matrix transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$Let \ ψ\ :{Mat }_{ 2x2 }(ℝ)\ →\ { Mat }_{ 2x2 }(ℝ)\ be\ defined\ by$

$ ψ : \pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}→\pmatrix{a+b&a-c\\a+c&b-c}$ .

Find basis for ker ψ

I'm not sure how to do it for a matrix, I've set $\pmatrix{a+b&a-c\\a+c&b-c}$ to the zero matrix, and obtained 4 equations, but not sure how proceed from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Easy Way**

Assuming that $\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ are being though of as additive groups, the kernel is made up of all matrices that are send to the zero matrix. So you need $a+b=0$, $a-c=0$, $a+c=0$ and $b-c=0$. Well, $a+b=0$ if and only if $a=-b$. Let's substitute that into the remaining three equations: $-b-c=0$, $-b+c=0$ and $b-c=0$. Well, $-b-c=0$ if and only if $b=-c$. Let's put that into the two remaining equations: $-(-c)+c=0$ and $-(-c)-c=0$. Well, $2c=0$ if and only if $c=0$. Hence $a=-b$, $b=-c$ and $c=0$ meaning that $a=b=c=0$.

You're free to choose $d$. So the matrix $\left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right]$ spans the kernel.

Comment: Oh thanks, I was having problem solving the 4 equations, but I followed your argument, and it makes sense, but shouldn't last equation be b - c = 0, which means -c - c = 0, gives -2c = 0, instead of 2c = 0 ?

Comment: @Dexter That's right, *thanks*! I'd written them in the wrong order. I've corrected it now. But don't worry: $-2c=0 \iff +2c = 0$.

Comment: So would the basis of kernel be: span $\left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right]$ ? Since it's linearly independent and spanning

Comment: @Dexter Exactly! There's only one, non-zero element so a spanning set is a basis.

Comment: I, personally, prefer another answwer; but this is really the simple easy undrestandable way @Dexter: so +1

Comment: @Babak S. Yeah this is the one I've seen on my problem sheets, and one I'm most comfortable with, but you're welcome to post your own version if you wish I guess.

Comment: @Dexter: Thanks for you kind words, but Fly by Night did all you need to know about this problem. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** First identify $\text{Mat}_{2 \times 2}$ with $\mathbb{R}^4$, with basis matrices $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, ...,$$ and write $\psi$ as a linear transformation $\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ with matrix $M$.

Then read the examples [in this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28matrix%29), which give a method for finding a basis once you have a matrix.